# 2 raised to power n without any loop or recursion or library function

Tags: c++, templates

The below program calculates 2 raised to the power n without using any loop,runtime recursion or  library function[pow].
It uses ***TEMPLATE METAPROGRAMMING*** technique.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int n> struct funStruct
{
    enum { val = 2*funStruct<n-1>::val };
};

template<> struct funStruct<0>
{
    enum { val = 1 };
};

int main()
{
    cout << funStruct<8>::val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**I was wandering that can i use function in place of structure?**

Comment: How does this not use recursion? It happens compile-time - but that's obvious, because the argument is passed as a template parameter, so the calculation happens at compile time too.

Comment: The whole point of this particular meta-programming example is that 2^n is calculated (recursively) at compile-time, not run-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious solution, as @tdammes points out is just a non-iterative non-recursive approach:

```
constexpr int pow2( unsigned pwr ) {
   return 1 << per;
}
```

By using `constexpr` the compiler will compute the result at compile time and yield a compile time constant. If you still want to use recursion, you can:

```
constexpr int pow2( unsigned pwr ) {
   return pwr==0? 1 : 2*pow2(pwr-1);
}
```

Which is basically the same compile time recursion than your metaprogramming trick in a slightly more concise and easy to read manner. The use of `constexpr`, of course, requires C++11, so if you don't have it, you can always use either the original metaprogramming trick, or @tdammers approach adapted:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct pow2 {
   static const unsigned int value = 1 << N;
};
```

Comment: There is a misstyping error per => pwr in the first code sample.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of the obvious solution:

```
unsigned int power_of_two(unsigned int power) {
    return (1 << power);
}
```

You could support signed powers, but that would be pointless in integer math, because all negative powers of 2 are less than 1 and would truncate down to 0.